# Making a paragraph divided into two paragraphs based on a particular word or word pair

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (2 column data frame). The column with text will be divided into two columns based on the presence of a word. In this case, the word pair is `unit #2`. The new data will have a column 2 with the sentences before `unit #2` and the new column 3 with the sentences starting with `unit #2`.

```
report <- data.frame(Text = c("unit #1 stopped at a stop sign on a road. unit #1 was speeding. unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #2 of 3 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time  and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was unmindful.", 
                              "unit #1 stopped there. unit #1 was under influence of drug. unit #2 travelling northbound. unit #2 was not unmindful. unit #2 crashed into unit #1.", 
                              "unit #1 was going straight. unit #1 was not speeding. unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #1 of 2 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was driving fast."), id = 1:3)
```

Comment: `unit #2` appears 3 times in the text. Simple `separate` function will split each Text into 4 columns.

Comment: this work? `spl <- 'unit #2'; cbind(report, read.table(text = sub(spl, paste0(';', spl), report$Text, fixed = TRUE), sep = ';', comment.char = ''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tidyr's `extract` with non-greedy regex:

(Add `remove = FALSE` if you want to keep column 1.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

report <- data.frame(Text = c(
  "unit #1 stopped at a stop sign on a road. unit #1 was speeding. unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #2 of 3 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time  and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was unmindful.",
  "unit #1 stopped there. unit #1 was under influence of drug. unit #2 travelling northbound. unit #2 was not unmindful. unit #2 crashed into unit #1.",
  "unit #1 was going straight. unit #1 was not speeding. unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #1 of 2 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was driving fast."
), id = 1:3)
  
df <- report |> 
  extract(Text, into = c("column 2", "column 3"), regex = "(.*?(?=unit #2))(.*)")

df

#>                                                           column 2
#> 1 unit #1 stopped at a stop sign on a road. unit #1 was speeding. 
#> 2     unit #1 stopped there. unit #1 was under influence of drug. 
#> 3           unit #1 was going straight. unit #1 was not speeding. 
#>                                                                                                                                   column 3
#> 1   unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #2 of 3 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time  and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was unmindful.
#> 2                                                  unit #2 travelling northbound. unit #2 was not unmindful. unit #2 crashed into unit #1.
#> 3 unit #2 travelling southbound  in lane #1 of 2 lanes. unit #2 couldn't react in time and crashed into unit #1. unit #2 was driving fast.
#>   id
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
#> 3  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>